# How can a threadpool be reused after shutdown

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a .csv file containing over 70 million lines of which each line is to generate a **Runnable** and then executed by threadpool. This Runnable will insert a record into Mysql.

What's more , I want to record a position of the csv file for the **RandomAccessFile** to locate. The position is written to a **File**.I want to write this record when all the threads in threadpool are finished.So ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown() is invoked. But when more lines come, I need a threadpool again. How can I reuse this current threadpool instead of make a new one.

The code is as follows:

```
public static boolean processPage() throws Exception {

    long pos = getPosition();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    raf.seek(pos);
    if(pos==0)
        raf.readLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < PAGESIZE; i++) {
        String lineStr = raf.readLine();
        if (lineStr == null)
            return false;
        String[] line = lineStr.split(",");
        final ExperienceLogDO log = CsvExperienceLog.generateLog(line);
        //System.out.println("userId: "+log.getUserId()%512);

        pool.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    experienceService.insertExperienceLog(log);
                } catch (BaseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    BufferedWriter resultWriter = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    RESULT_FILENAME), true)));
    resultWriter.write("\n");
    resultWriter.write(String.valueOf(raf.getFilePointer()));
    resultWriter.close();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
    System.out.println(time);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), you cannot reuse an `ExecutorService` that has been shut down. I'd recommend against any *workarounds*, since (a) they may not work as expected in all situations; and (b) you can achieve what you want using standard classes.

You must either

1. instantiate a new `ExecutorService`; or
2. not terminate the `ExecutorService`.

The first solution is easily implemented, so I won't detail it.

For the second, since you want to execute an action once all the submitted tasks have finished, you might take a look at [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) and use it instead. It wraps an `ExecutorService` which will do the thread management, but the runnables will get wrapped into something that will tell the `ExecutorCompletionService` when they have finished, so it can report back to you:

```
ExecutorService executor = ...;
ExecutorCompletionService ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService(executor);

for (int i = 0; i < totalTasks; i++) {
  ... ecs.submit(...); ...
}

for (int i = 0; i < totalTasks; i++) {
  ecs.take();
}
```

The method `take()` on the `ExecutorCompletionService` class will block until a task has finished (either normally or abruptly). It will return a `Future`, so you can check the results if you wish.

I hope this can help you, since I didn't completely understand your problem.

Comment: how do i force stopping the threads or cancel all tasks ? using exectuer.shutdownNow() ? will it work fine even with this wrapper?

Answer (score 4):

create and group all tasks and submit them to the pool with [invokeAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) (which only returns when all tasks are successfully completed)

Comment: What is better approach to use `ExecutorCompletionService` or `invokeAll`?

Answer (score 4):

After calling shutdown on a ExecutorService, [no new Task will be accepted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--). This means you have to create a new ExecutorService for each round of tasks.

However, with Java 8 [ForkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#awaitQuiescence-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) was introduced. If you can switch from a normal ExecutorService to ForkJoinPool, you can use this method to wait until no more tasks are running in a ForkJoinPool without having to call shutdown. This means you can fill a ForkJoinPool with Tasks, waiting until it is empty (quiescent), and then again begin filling it with Tasks, and so on.