# How to reuse ThreadPoolExecutor after shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

In my application i have used a custom ThreadPoolExecutor which enables pausing and resuming of the Executor by extending the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class. Same way I want to have Restart functionality implemented where after the shutdown method of the `ExecutorService` has been executed. I first tried with creating new instance of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and it failed. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722546/how-can-a-threadpool-be-reused-after-shutdown) and tried the `ExecutorCompletionService` which resulted the same failure where it didn't executed as intended.

First time when I click the start button in my UI it executes fine and after the completion of the process when I again start, it won't give me the intended result. Instead will give me the same previous result of the first run. What is the best suitable way which I can achieve this task ?
Thanks in advance :)

Following lines will be executed at each button click.

```
    private static int jobs = 10;
    ExecutorService executor = new PausableThreadPoolExecutor(num_threads, num_threads, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(jobs));
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new TaskToDo(jobs);
        executor.submit(worker);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}
    System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is the source I used to have pause/resume implementation.

Comment: Please show some code and describe what is "the intended result"

Comment: Still I don't get it what is the issue? Did you manage to make your pause/resume executorService? 
Restarting an executorService after a shutdown is against the executorService specification so you should never try doing this. If you try to do so for solving your pause/resume issue this is not the good way to go

Comment: @olator I included the source i used to have pause and resume implemented. If so what is the suitable way to achieve multithreaded execution pause, resume, stop and restart ?

Comment: Yes pause/resume is all fine but shutdown and then restart is not acceptable: from ExecutorService API : "Upon termination, an executor has no tasks actively executing, no tasks awaiting execution, and no new tasks can be submitted". Just create a new one after a shutdown. Or don't do a shutdown if you want this executorService to be useable again

Comment: @olator true. but each button click executes above code. there each time new ExecutorService is created. but still problem remains.

Comment: What problem you never described your problem at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor you can restart it [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)
using this the methods can return a ScheduledFuture [ScheduledFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) or a Future [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to hold references to the tasks

```
ScheduledFuture now = null;
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
Runnable runner = new Runnable(){
                public void run()
                {
                    rollthedice(); //your method or runnable of choice
                }
            };
```

to start and restart something like "theres other methods too"

```
now = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 0, 250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

to cancel or stop

```
now.cancel(true);
now = null;
```

Comment: your suggested restart will work differently. this will start in each 250ms. am i correct..???

Comment: yes, you should use Future and the method scheduler.submit(Runnable task) instead of ScheduledFuture and scheduleatfixedrate, i dont have an example i just seen that you put your code up, the link to the docs are up there