# How to restart a ExecutorService after shut down

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I have a class A which implements Runnable and its main job is to take items from a queue and send them to an external API.

I also have a pre-load class in the project which has an initialize()method and destroy() method and will load all the necessary components. I use ExecutorService to create thread pool in the initialize()method and shutdown() the executor in the destroy() method.

Now I have a problem when class A sends items to the external API, sometimes the API will return 500 to indicate there is a server problem. So in that situation, I want the executor to shut down for 15 sec, then restart and continue to take items from a queue and send them to external API. Is there any way for Executor to do that?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by shutting down the executor? Do you want to stop accepting new incoming messages, or something else?

Comment: @yegodm I don't want the thread to take items from the queue and send them.

Comment: No - once an ExecutorService is shutdown there is no way to submit/invoke new tasks.  A different approach would be to share a variable such as `AtomicBoolean shouldPause` among the threads and when the threads need to pause update the variable to true.  Each thread can check the shared variable and sleep as needed.  Or the thread submitting to the `ExecutorService` can check the variable and sleep.

Comment: @Andrew S So if I don't want the thread to sleep, the only way is to create a new Executor?

Comment: If the Executor is shutdown then a new instance would be required - see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722546/how-can-a-threadpool-be-reused-after-shutdown).

Comment: I would probably try to use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` where your runnable would run as usual. On 500 error it would exit but resubmit itself 15 seconds ahead as another task.

Comment: You need to replace it with another one.